# CESIUM ERROR "ReferenceError: $ is not defined " (writing in SANDCASTLE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cesiumjs, sandcastle

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

i tried insesrt:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but cesium not works like ordinary platfroms

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You need to make sure that the `<script>` is fully loaded before you attempt to use the jQuery `$` object.

Comment: `<style>@import url(../templates/bucket.css);</style>
    
    <div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
    <div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
    <div id="toolbar"></div>` this is all what CESIUM provide in HTML body & CSS. Where should i put <script> ?

Comment: are you trying in Sandcastle?

Comment: I don't know Cesium, but a quick search told me that it has a [loadJson](https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/b29/Documentation/loadJson.html) feature that will do just about the same as `$.ajax`, without the trouble of having to get jQuery working.

Comment: yes, im trying in Sandcastle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: no, im still struggling :/ @Liam The problem is something related about Sandcastle, because for example in replit.com IDE works everything fine. So it is my lack of competence about Sandcastle

Comment: It would probably help if you included the [tag:sandcastle] tag then

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just do [what is suggest here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461880/cesium-error-referenceerror-is-not-defined-writing-in-sandcastle?noredirect=1#comment124556306_70461880). In 2021/2022 you really don't need jquery

Comment: Or even use the native [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). without using an libraries at all

Comment: Try to give more details on what you wish to achieve.

Comment: im trying to achieve drones position (longitude,latitude,height) in real time and use these coordinates to animate flight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cesium's "Sandcastle" test environment does not include a means to include JQuery.  Instead, you can use Cesium's own helper functions for things like this, such as [Cesium.Resource.fetchJson](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Resource.html#.fetchJson).

For example:  [Live Sandcastle Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=bY/BasMwDIZfRfjSFIrNduzSUOitjBVW2MkX11EbU0fObCWlG333xdkGG5sOAkn/J/0aTITB4QUjrIDwAhtMrm/ly9QrtLBTvQnExhFGLeYPmjR9yZ4xhT5alEdk22xToOJdE0Af/RK0aJi7tFQq4mvEJB0p0znV05nChdS9Fppuc8kNUlEbNrCqYMJtoBQ8Sh9OxXa/e5KJo6OTO14n3QKo934BMxhjNs+ObjmJhSgTXz1WecnatV2InL0UUirGtvOGMalDb8/I0qaUoVJ9I2XtBnD16p+nwXqT0jg5jof37g21qEo16n9hPph6tLkbMHpzzZLmrnr8bEopSzWWfykOwR9M/LExv/UB)

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

Cesium.Resource.fetchJson({
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/unknown/2"
}).then(data => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '    '));
});
```